# What is wrong with this CodePen?

Tags: reactjs, codepen

I have spent almost an hour trying to get React working in Codepen.  I've set up React and ReactDom as well as Babel in my JS settings.  I've pasted examples of code from other working react codepen examples in my own pen and they don't work.

```
function Test() {
  return <div>tesst</div>
}

const app = document.getElementById('app');
ReactDom.render(<Test />, app);
```

https://codepen.io/alexbollbach/pen/jaZBPG?editors=1111

Comment: ReactDOM instead of ReactDom - `ReactDOM.render(<Test />, app);`

Comment: thanks.  i wasn't seeing any "ReactDom is undefined" or anything.  so i spent a half an hour of my short window of free time this morning on spelling.  awesome!!

Comment: Look at the browser`s console. It seems like the codepen console doesn't display errors

Comment: good idea!  i will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo:

**ReactDom** should be **ReactDOM**

Here's a working pen

```
function Test() {
  return <div>tesst</div>
}

const app = document.getElementById('app');
ReactDOM.render(<Test />, app);
```

https://codepen.io/Lokuzt/pen/bYLqMa

It works after correcting the typo

Comment: thanks.  yes this was a half an hour spelling mistake.

Comment: @AlexBollbach Happens to everyone :D